# Writing text on existing image

Tags: c#, asp.net, image

I'm trying to script some ASP.NET page that will get an existing image and add text into it. Then I want the image (with the text) to be shown in the page like it's a .png page so it can be loaded in forums and such.
This is my code as of now:

```
Bitmap bitMapImage = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(Server.MapPath("~/Images/sigbg.png"));
Graphics graphicImage = Graphics.FromImage(bitMapImage);
graphicImage.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
graphicImage.DrawString("Test", new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 12, FontStyle.Bold), SystemBrushes.WindowText, 0,0);
graphicImage.DrawArc(new Pen(Color.Red, 3), 0, 0, 150, 50, 0, 360);
Response.ContentType = "image/png";
bitMapImage.Save(Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Png);
graphicImage.Dispose();
bitMapImage.Dispose();
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't add the text to the image and saves it as the original image. Then the page shows the "new" image but no text. How can this be solved?

Comment: did you try saving the image AFTER disposing the graphics?

Comment: I've set my code and it doesn't work either. Edited my post with the new code..

Comment: what is the predominant color of sigbg.png?

Comment: http://img1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20121208002227/gtawiki/images/b/b9/Vinewood-Streets-Background.jpg This is the pic, just resized it to 250x120px @MikeNakis

Comment: strange, that's of a light color, so `SystemBrushes.WindowText` should show on it.

Comment: @MikeNakis I have a new code that doesn't save the image on a new file (because I actually don't need it to), it uses `.DrawString` and `.DrawArc` methods. Arc is showing but `String` isn't.. I'll post the code in my question.

Comment: Aha, then what happens if you draw your text not on 0, 0 but on 20, 20 ?

Comment: @MikeNakis It's still not drawing it.

Comment: I do not know what's wrong, man.  Have you read this article? http://www.codemag.com/Article/03050801

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct and outputs the "test" and an ellipse in the left top corner. Make sure the page/image is not cached. For instance, if you put your code in an aspx page then try to call that page with a random query i.e. "image.aspx?12345" or clear cache in the browser.

Also you could try to add following code to avoid caching

```
Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-1));
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
```

Comment: My page is `Sig.aspx` and you have an `input text` for some name. Then when you submit the form, it redirects you to `Sig.aspx?Name=Request.Form["Name"]` and then it generates the image. Problem is the circle shows up but the string doesn't.. Tried with your provided code but didn't work as well.

Comment: The text is in black, are you drawing black on black maybe?

Comment: http://img1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20121208002227/gtawiki/images/b/b9/Vinewood-Streets-Background.jpg, no black on black here..

Comment: I think I found out why it doesn't draw the string (though I don't know why). The original image is of type `jpeg` while the image I use is a resize of it and of type `png` instead. I resized it using Photoshop. Can this be resolved?

Comment: If you resized it and saved as png and used `System.Drawing.Bitmap(Server.MapPath("~/Images/sigbg.png"))` then it is 100% correct. That fact that the old image was in jpeg does not change anything.

Comment: Anyway it worked with another image. All solved, thanks!